# Transpose query in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery

I have a simple cfquery which outputs 3 columns with their respective data. The columns are name, address and age.

I want to transpose this set of data so that the names become the columns and the address and age are displayed under each column.

I know that we can use QueryAddColumn or something like this for this issue. Can someone help me out with this problem?

EDIT:
Based on the comment below this is the intended output:

```
Oct 2011          Nov 2011          Dec 2011          Jan 2012          Feb 2012
NumberofPeople    NumberofPeople    NumberofPeople    NumberofPeople    NumberofPeople
EmploymentRate    EmploymentRate    EmploymentRate    EmploymentRate    EmploymentRate
```

Comment: Can you update the tags to indicate your database type and version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have included a sample data row at the top where you would put your cfquery statement.

```
<cfset firstQuery = queryNew("date,NumberofPeople,EmploymentRate")>
<cfset aRow = queryAddRow(firstQuery)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"date","OCT_2011",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"NumberofPeople","28",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"EmploymentRate","50%",aRow)>

<cfset aRow = queryAddRow(firstQuery)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"date","NOV_2011",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"NumberofPeople","28",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"EmploymentRate","56%",aRow)>

<cfset aRow = queryAddRow(firstQuery)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"date","DEC_2011",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"NumberofPeople","29",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"EmploymentRate","55%",aRow)>

<cfset aRow = queryAddRow(firstQuery)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"date","JAN_2012",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"NumberofPeople","30",aRow)>
<cfset querySetCell(firstQuery,"EmploymentRate","52%",aRow)>



<!--- Will Create new query with names as column headers--->
<cfset newQuery = queryNew(valueList(firstQuery.date,','))> 

<!--- Will Create new query with names as column headers--->

<cfset people = queryAddRow(newQuery)>
<cfset rate = queryAddRow(newQuery)>

<cfloop query='firstQuery'>
    <!---Syntax for this function is: QuerySetCell(query, column_name, value [, row_number ]) --->
    <cfset querySetCell(newQuery,firstQuery.date,firstQuery.NumberofPeople,people)>
    <cfset querySetCell(newQuery,firstQuery.date,firstQuery.EmploymentRate,rate)>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#newQuery#">

<cfdump var="#ArrayToList(newQuery.getColumnNames())#">
```

This is How I would Do it, But I can't think of why I would do it. I'd be interested to hear your use case. Anyway, I hope this helps.

(P.S This is tested in CF9, so you should be able to copy and paste it to test for yourself.)

**EDIT -(Again):**

Forgot to mention, this can only work if the names your retrieveing from the DB are valid column names, so no spaces (In this example spaces in dates have been replaced by underscores)!

**>>>** New code snippet for the updated data structure, the function `valueList(firstQuery.date,',')` doesn't re-order your columns. The columns are re-ordered on output when dumping. I have used the function `ArrayToList(newQuery.getColumnNames())` to show that internally CF maintains the column order and you need only ask it nicely. You should be able to use all this information to nicely output your data how you need it.

Comment: Keep in mind the same "name" could appear multiple times, which would produce multiple columns named "John" for instance. It may not be an issue with their data, just something to be aware of ..

Comment: @Dpolehonski

Thanks for your help but I am still facing some minor issue though. Let me put to you my genuine case. I actually have Month and Year as the first column, then a 2nd column which display for example "NumberofPeople", then a third column which displayed "EmploymentRate".

So firstly it is important to display tranpose the column as such:

Oct 2011     Nov 2011     Dec 2011     Jan 2012     Feb 2012

Comment: As you can see they are in a specific order. By using your line of code:
 <cfset newQuery = queryNew(valueList(firstQuery.monthyear,','))>  

Firstly I am getting an error because of the space, secondly if I dont put the space as you suggested earlier, the column list is made in Alphabetical order (this should be be the case).

Can you put some further light on this. Can we tweak a bit your existing code to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: `query.columnList` is always alphabetical. You can use the array returned by `getMetaData(query)` to iterate through the columns in the original order. As far as spaces, you could substitute a character like an underscore  "_". Then restore it when you output the column names  ie `replace(colName, '_', ' ')`. You could also just use a sql `pivot` as Phillip suggested, rather than doing this in CF code. Assuming your database supports it.

Comment: query.getColumnNames() returns the same ordered array of columns. Its just undocumented because its part of the underlying java query object.

Comment: Why use an undocumented method when there is a documented function available?

Comment: I didn't want the other meta-data and that function return a single dimension ordered array.. if CF is built using the power and flexibility of Java then why not use it?

Comment: The usual danger of using undocumented code. It may change or go away in future versions and break your app. But that is the risk you take. I love the java stuff, but only use the *undocumented* parts when there is no alternative - or there is a significant benefit over the documented method.

Comment: @Dpolehonski
Well well, solution is nice..I am actually displaying the data in using Flash Builder 4.5 in a datagrid. Everything displays fine but still having the alphabetical ordering issue.

I actually looped in the initial query as such to get the column names:

<cfloop query="firstQuery">
   <cfset tmp = QueryAddColumn(newQuery,#firstQuery.date#,arrayNew(1))>
  </cfloop>

The above is same as valueList I suppose.

Comment: Unless you defined explicitly the order of your columns in flash builder it will ALWAYS output in alphabetical order. Its not a CF issue anymore, its a flash builder issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but it seems like a simple SQL query with the ORDER BY clause would work.  Something like this:

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasource="yourdatasourcename">
select name, address, age
from tablename
order by name
</cfquery>
```

Then in your ColdFusion output page, you can use the  tag with the group attribute.  Something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="myquery">
<p>name = #name#
    <cfoutput group="name">
    age = #age#
    address = #address#<br />
    </cfoutput>
</p>
</cfoutput>
```

Obviously, you can format the output however you wish.

EDIT --

If you are wanting to display like:

```
Mary        Joe       Sam           Suzie

28          36        25             42

123 Maple   16 Oak    3723 Street   832 Busy St.
```

Perhaps something like (I have not tested this, just brainstorming):

```
<cfoutput query="myquery" group="name">
<div style="float:left;">name = #name#
    <cfoutput>
    <p>
    age = #age#<br />
    address = #address#
    </p>
    </cfoutput>
</div>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I do not think that will transpose the names into *column headers*. If the db supports it, it may be simpler to do it at the db level.

Comment: Btw, I have not tested your updated code, but the `group` belongs in the top `cfoutput` tag to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: I updated the second code example by moving the 'group' attribute to the other 'cfoutput' tag.  I'm sure this will not be the end view that the OP wants but should be a step in that direction.  Thanks @Leigh

Comment: @Mike Thanks for editing my display output.  I tried to do that but could not.  I removed my comment about it not displaying correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing a pivot query in SQL.

Comment: True. Unfortunately he did not mention if his db type supports `pivot` or if his requirements dictated that it must be done in CF rather than sql.

Comment: @Leigh @ Phillips
I am using DB as database. I did not know about pivot tables. Grateful if you guys can set an example for my case. I am also trying it on my side :)

Comment: Not all databases support them. Which one are you using? I am not sure what `DB` means :) DB2?

Comment: @Leigh missed the "2" completely :) Its indeed DB2.

Comment: @FlexyBoz - Oh, sorry I have never used DB2.